# How to check if user authenticated using firebase in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-router

I have multiple pages in react project includes signin.js and signup.js. 
In my signin page , I can able to login and able to view the user details. But when I switch to signup page, I can't able to use the `{user}` in this code.
I want to see the logged user details in signup page too . Can somebody help to riddle this .
I'm new to react js .

```
signin.js
```

```
import React from 'react'
import withFirebaseAuth from 'react-with-firebase-auth'
import firebaseConfig from './firebaseConfig'
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

class signin extends React.Component {
    state = {
        email :'',
        password:''
    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.id] : e.target.value
        })
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error.code)
            console.log(error.message)
            if(error.code == 'auth/invalid-email') {
                alert("The email you have entered is in incorrect format")
            }
            else if(error.code == "auth/wrong-password"){
                alert("The password you have entered is incorrect")
            }
            else if(error.code == "auth/user-not-found") {
                alert("Email not found")
            }
            else if(error.code == "auth/too-many-requests"){
                alert("Too many requests.  Please try again after some time .")
            }
            else {
                alert(error.message)
            }
           })
    }
    render() {
        const {
            user,
            signOut,
            signInWithGoogle,
          } = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
                Signin
                <div className="container">  
                {
                    user 
                        ? <div><p>Hello, {user.displayName}</p>
                        <p>You profile :</p><img src={user.photoURL} width="50px" height="50px"></img><p>Your email : {user.email}</p></div>
                :         
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="white">
                        <div className="input-field">
                            <label htmlFor="email"> Email</label>
                            <input type = "text" id="email" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                        </div>
                        <div className="input-field">
                            <label htmlFor="password"> Password</label>
                            <input type="password" id ="password" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                        </div>
                        <div className="input-field">
                            <button  className ="btn pink lighten-2 z-depth-0">Login</button> 
                        </div>
                    </form>
                }
                {/* {
            user
              ? <div><p>Hello, {user.displayName}</p><p>Your email : {user.email}</p></div>
              : <p>Please sign in.</p>
          } */}

          {
            user
              ? <button className="btn blue lighten-2 z-depth-0" onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
              : <button className="btn blue lighten-2 z-depth-0" onClick={signInWithGoogle}>Sign in with Google</button>
          }
            </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const firebaseAppAuth = firebaseApp.auth();
const loginAuth = firebaseApp.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword;
const providers = {
  googleProvider: new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider(),
};

export default withFirebaseAuth({
  providers,
  firebaseAppAuth,
  loginAuth,
})(signin);
```

```
signup.js
```

```
import React from 'react'
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
export default class signup extends React.Component {
    state = {
        email :'',
        password:'',
        firstName:'',
        lastName:''
    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.id] : e.target.value
        })
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(this.state)
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then((user) => {
            console.log(user)}).catch(function(error) {
            alert('Error :'+error.message);
           })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            SignUp
            <div className="container">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="white">
                    <div className="input-field">
                        <label htmlFor="FirstName"> First Name</label>
                        <input type = "text" id="firstName" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-field">
                        <label htmlFor="lastName"> Last Name</label>
                        <input type = "text" id="lastName" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-field">
                        <label htmlFor="email"> Email</label>
                        <input type = "text" id="email" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-field">
                        <label htmlFor="password"> Password</label>
                        <input type="text" id ="password" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-field">
                        <button  className ="btn pink lighten-2 z-depth-0">Signup</button> 
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: you can save data in local storage, after login and you can access local storage in anywhere in your project

Comment: @AmitRai Hi, thanks. I'm new to react js . Can I use state or any other thing to do it?Could you please specify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add this function in `componentDidMount()` to check whether your user is already signed in or not.
If you need to access this user info in other points in your app, I would suggest separating any logic pertaining to authentication into a separate component, then passing the data around either using `redux`, `contextApi`, or simply as props to the rest of your app.

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    var displayName = user.displayName;
    var email = user.email;
    var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
    var photoURL = user.photoURL;
    var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
    var uid = user.uid;
    var providerData = user.providerData;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out.
    // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: It didn't work . Could you please explain this or how can I use componentDidmount() ?

Comment: componentDidMount is lifecycle method for React classes. Basically it will execute a piece of code only once, after your component has rendered for the first time.  Check my other answer for a coded example.

Answer (score 1):

Once your component is rendered for the first time, componentDidMount will run.  If your user is logged, the onAuthStateChanged function will have access to {user} which contains your user's information.  You can then save this info to your components state, via this.setState({email:user.email}) for example.

```js
class signin extends React.Component {
        state = {
            email :'',
            password:''
        }
    
      componentDidMount() {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
            if (user) {
                console.log(user)
                this.setState({email:user.email})
            }
    
        }
    
        handleChange = (e) => {
            this.setState({
                [e.target.id] : e.target.value
            })
        }
```